# Approximating difference betwen $\log$ function

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

How should the difference between $\log$ at different points $a, b$ be approximated (say via the Taylor series)?

So, I'm trying to approximate the following term $\log(a) - \log(b)$ where $a, b \in [0,1]$ and I'm confused between two possible options:

- Treat $\log(a) - \log(b) = \log(\frac{a}{b}) \approx (\frac{a}{b} - 1)$
- Or, do this $\log(a) - \log(b) = (a - 1) - (b - 1) = (a - b)$. According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494332/taylor-expansion-of-difference-of-functions), the approach is the way to go about it.

I'm confused about which of these provides a "better" approximation of the difference.

Additionally, I wanted to know if my approach should change if I want to approximate $\log(A) - \log(B)$ where $A, B \in S$ are operators and $S$ is a convex set.

Comment: The first approximation works if $a/b\approx1$, the latter if $a\approx1,\,b\approx1$, but neither works well in general on $[0,\,1]^2$, i.e. for $a/b\in[0,\,\infty]$. That's a big topic (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/698384).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was pretty helpful